# replicate image with form data

Tags: php, laravel

On Store function I `replicate()` form data as following:

```
    public function store(StoreNewsRequest $request)
            {
                 $news = News::create($request->all());
        
                if ($request->input('image', false)) {
                    $news->addMedia(storage_path('tmp/uploads/' . $request->input('image')))->toMediaCollection('image');
                }
                if ($media = $request->input('ck-media', false)) {
                    Media::whereIn('id', $media)->update(['model_id' => $news->id]);
                }
    
                $assigned_pack_ids = DB::table('content_pack_news')->where('news_id' , $news->id)->pluck('content_pack_id')->toArray();
                
                foreach($assigned_pack_ids as $key => $pack_id) {
                    $news_replica = $news->replicate();
                    $news_replica->save();      
                    
                    DB::table('content_pack_news')->insert(['content_pack_id' => $pack_id,'news_id' => $news_replica->id]);
                }

                return redirect()->route('admin.news.index');
    }
```

This testing code currently replicates the form data to 3 entries by `foreach($assigned_pack_ids`
But I get the uploaded image only on the first original entry.

How to `copy` the same image to all entries with different name for example `image_name_assigned_pack_id` and assign to the `replicate` data?

Comment: what is `addMedia` doing? how is it related to the entity?

Comment: @lagbox `addMedia` is assicated with `Laravel-medialibrary`  `Spatie` https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-medialibrary/v10/introduction